# Taking multiple text inputs from a form and output sentence

Tags: javascript, forms, function, class, console.log

I need to take five inputs from text into a form, with a single block for each input, and output a sentence equating to this:
(firstName) (lastName) has the role of (role) in (class) section (sectionNumber)
note that I can not use onclick.
I'll be honest, html I can figure out, javascript not so much. I dont event know where to start looking for an answer. do i need an array? If i need to change my html thats ok, but i know my js is absolutley not working. Any help at all would be apreciate!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a>Enter First Name</a>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="firstName"></input>
        <br>
        <a>Enter Last Name</a>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="lastName"></input>
        <br>
        <a>Enter Your Course</a>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="course"></input>
        <br>
        <a>Enter Your Section</a>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="section"></input>
        <br>
        <a>Enter Your Role</a>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="role"></input>
        <p id="nameOutput"></p>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit">

        <script>
            function sentence(firstName,lastName,course,section,role){
                this.sentence = sentence;
            }

            sentence.prototype.speak = function(){
                console.log('${firstName}+${lastName} has the role of ${role} in ${class} section ${section}.');
            }
   

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

i was atempting to use the class function to create a whole sentence without draging all of the elements declared in my html over one by one. as it is, i get no output. but i have a feeling if i did get an output, it would be incorect.

Comment: To get value of each input you can `document.getElementById("role").value`

Answer (score 0):

If you react on the "input" event of each input field you can get along without the "submit" button:

```js
const [fn, ln, crs, sct, rol, out] ="firstName,lastName,course,section,role,nameOutput"
  .split(",").map(id=>document.getElementById(id));

document.body.addEventListener("input",showit);
showit();

function showit(){out.textContent=`${fn.value} ${ln.value} has the role of ${rol.value} in ${crs.value}, section ${sct.value}.`}
```

```html
<label>Enter First Name</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="firstName" value="Harry">
<br>
<label>Enter Last Name</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="lastName" value="Potter">
<br>
<label>Enter Your Course</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="course" value="Magic Creatures">
<br>
<label>Enter Your Section</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="section" value="B">
<br>
<label>Enter Your Role</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="role" value="apprentice">
<p id="nameOutput"></p>
```

I also replaced your `<a>` elements with `<label>` elements.